# amp step up and source's durability

Tags: amperage, alternator

I have a 330w alternator, it is a washing machine alternator rating at 220V and 1.5A

I am trying to make Windmill to charge my battery UPS system (24V Sys), what I want to know is can I get a 24V 15A out of the alternator? And can the alternator handle it? Also how can I do it?

I am new to electronics, I barely have electricity and no teacher nor anyone would like to teach our help me (the people here are quite stingy even though they don't know much) so it ids a real pain to learn this.

What do I need to know? Where can I find few schematics I can relate and learn from? And is it ok to do what I want to do?

I am guessing that the alternator would be outputting AC power so I knew I will have to rectify it (am I wrong? And how can I know?) But I don't know how to step up amps nor if it had any effects on the alternator, I also need it to push as much amps as possible and not wait for the load take what it needs (in this case a battery)

Please help

Comment: "Washing machine alternator"??? do you mean a washing machine motor, converted to an alternator?

Comment: Have you multiplied the numbers yet, to find out how much power is generated and consumed?

Comment: It is a washing machine motor, but If I supply a movement to it then it will give me electricity right? I can't be picky... poor and unstable country, no government, no shippings available, most people are uneducated so it's ridiculously hard finding what I need... I was planning to use a car's battery charging alternator (12v 100A with AVR) but it's too heavy for the windmill (not easy to turn and needs high RPM)

Comment: Don't worry about consumption, I just need it to charge the batteries.. if I get it to work I will make enough for 1.5kw, inverter is morally off since I only have 400w solar system (250w usable) and my consumption is more than that

Comment: I think you need a more basic knowledge of electronics before you can build something like this. Read some books, tutorials on internet. When I was a boy I knew absolutely no-one who could teach me about electronics. So I went to the library and read all the books on electronics :-)

Comment: No libraries here.. no electricity and bad internet as well! I understand that but I really can't help it, my only help is the "Every circuit" app and another in android.. and I can't wait that long, I will learn in in a day If I have to! And I can.. I just need the right directition! I really need it now more than ever!

Comment: What I need to know is: is it possible? Or will the motor burn? Or does the amps Getty high after the circut? Also what law should I be likin looking at? And where can I find 3 current schematics that does this? I am only asking because it is really hard to research with my limited online time as well as the fact that most entries online don't help me at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what kind of motor it is. It will probably output AC. There's a chance that it might not output anything at all though. Some "induction" motors need something to kick start the rotor's magnetic field.

That aside, for any motor that you decide to use as an alternator, you can play around with them as described below, to see if it's appropriate.

Connect a resistive load (A high power resistor) across the motor's terminals, and measure the voltage across it while it is being turned at the expected top speed. Try measuring DC voltage first - if it shows around zero volts, then it's probably AC. If you then measure AC and it shows nearly zero volts, it's probably an induction motor that won't work for you.

The resistor's value (both power rating in watts, and the resistance in ohms) should be determined as follows:

If the motor runs off 220V, at 1.5A, then the power rating of the resistor should be this value or greater:

220 x 1.5 = 330 Watts

The resistance should be roughly:

220 / 1.5 = 147 ohms.

If anything, make it higher rather than lower. You should be able to source a 150 ohm resistor pretty easily. If necessary, you can build it yourself with resistance wire, making your own wire-wound resistor.

Once you know what sort of voltage waveform (AC/DC, peak voltage) and the sort of current (peak) you can then start working on a circuit which will use the electricity generated by it to charge your UPS system. This circuit depends highly on your findings from the above, and the requirements of your UPS system and how it will be used.

So I suggest you do the above, then ask another question, posting your findings (and the UPS requirements and how it will be used).

You will probably be able to use just about any motor - the question is how efficient will it be, which depends mostly on the motor's design, but other factors too. Some motors will work better as alternators than others.

Edit:

The steps you would then take would be:

1. Convert a 220v 1.5A AC supply to 22v 15A AC supply using a step-down transformer. Pretty much any AC to AC transformer such as those used to power low voltage halogen lights. However if your UPS is a 24V system, you will probably need an output more in the range of 33V/10A since for best efficiency the voltage will need to be a bit higher than the battery you're charging.
2. Use the output of that and convert it to an appropriate DC supply (look at mains to DC power supply circuits. It will need a rectifier as a minimum, but probably smoothing circuit and voltage regulator as well).
3. Then finally you will use that DC supply to power a circuit that charges the battery. For that, research "Lead acid battery charging circuits". UPS 24v Lead acid batteries typically need a charging voltage of around 27V. You will also want to limit the current, too much charging current will damage them. Use the battery's datasheets to find out how best to charge them, then research circuits that will do the job.

The above is pretty involved. You would certainly have an awful lot of learning to do. Being safe is the most important thing, and at the voltages of your motors, you are playing with fire. I don't think anyone can instruct you at your level of electronics knowledge to do this from scratch safely.

There is no way you're going to do this in a day. Nor a week. I'd be surprised if you managed it in a month. If you really want to get into this, I suggest a book called "The Art of Electronics". It will give you the theory behind everything you need to know (and more). But count yourself lucky if you complete this project within a year. I suggest biting the bullet and just importing a system that is ready to go.

Comment: If it works, would boosting the amps to 15A damage it? Or it has nothing to do with it and that would be on the circuit's side?

Comment: Also can you direct me to a good place I could learn on how to manipulate amps? Most tutorials are very basic or just complete gebrish!

Comment: You should not exceed the motor's rated RPM, nor the motor's current rating (amps). Excessive RPM will damage it mechanically, and excessive current (or voltage) can destroy the coils.

Comment: So it is not possible to convert it to 12V 15A through a circuit since it only rates at 1.5A? As for the RPM I know that and will make a breaking and emergency breaking system

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood. Yes, you can use a circuit (transformer) to convert, for example 220v/1.5A to 22v/15A. (Although the converter circuit will not be 100% efficient). See my edits.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And with determination anything is possible! Never under estimate the ability of the human brain! Beside I am at a corner right now.. so importing/ready systems/knowledged technicians are out of the picture.. those are impossible! I don't even know if I would find the parts I need...but have to do it! Again, thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome :) Good luck, and be safe!